# Firebase serverTimestamp older than

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling with a simple check of a date in firestore.
I save a serverTimestamp object to the database.

Now I want to check if this date is older than 23h, without using a local date object, because that could be modified by the user or have a different timezone.

Can someone help me with this, cant find anything useful so far.

Thx a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to use a server-side timestamp as the value in a query.

The closest you can get is using a local date/time from the client and then validating that in the security rules of your database.

Also see:

- [Firestore use database/server time for query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283805/firestore-use-database-server-time-for-query).
- [The secrets of Firestore’s FieldValue.serverTimestamp()](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/the-secrets-of-firestore-fieldvalue-servertimestamp-revealed-29dd7a38a82b)
- [Allow read in FireStore rules based on timestamp value in document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414073/allow-read-in-firestore-rules-based-on-timestamp-value-in-document)